# Python/tox Install a dependency as editable

Tags: python, testing, tox

In [tox.ini](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example/basic.html), you specify the packages that you want  [tox](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) to install in the virtualenvs it creates.

```
[testenv]
deps =
    mock
    pytest
commands =
    python setup.py test -q
    python setup.py flake8
```

This example tells tox to install mock and pytest in to each virtualenv before running the tests. Tox will use pip to install those dependencies from PyPI.

How do I tell tox to `pip install -e` one dependency from a local checkout instead of from PyPI? I still want the rest of the dependencies to be installed from PyPI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to remove the dependency from the deps variable, and just run the local pip install as the first command that tox will execute in its test run.

```
[testenv]
deps =
    mock
commands =
    pip install -e ~/path/to/pytest
    python setup.py test -q
    python setup.py flake8
```